# Configuring where Java HBS looks for partial templates

Tags: java, maven, templates, handlebars.js, partials

In short, Java HBS (jknack.handlebars) is looking for my **partial** templates in a very different directory than the parent templates.  Does any one know how to configure where jknack.handlebars looks for partial templates?

I need to avoid:
***Error in createLayeredHtml..
        com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /com/XXX/YYY/inline@53ce2ca5.hbs:598:8: The partial '/com/XXX/YYY/temp-templates/CarouselHeader.hbs' could not be found***

This is parent template:

```
  <div data-module="{{type}}" data-module-id="{{module_id}}" class="slick-module athena-item-page-carousel">

{{> temp-templates/CarouselHeader}}

<div class="js-carousel-n-up carousel carousel-narrow carousel-banner carousel-n-up-responsive">
    {{> temp-templates/CarouselFirstTile}}
```

**UPDATE:**
I should have said, the default location that HBS is looking is my (please forgive me if this is not the proper term) main directory of my package in java.  Its looking in /src/main/java/com/company/project .  Isnt there a way to point it to something like /src/main/resources ?

This is the complete Error:

```
[ERROR] 2015-09-18 17:23:34.688 [main] 
Error in createLayeredHtml..
    com.github.jknack.handlebars.HandlebarsException: /com/XXX/YYY/inline@53ce2ca5.hbs:598:8: The partial '/com/XXX/YYY/temp-templates/CarouselHeader.hbs' could not be found
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.Partial.merge(Partial.java:142)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:128)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.TemplateList.merge(TemplateList.java:61)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:128)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:115)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Options.apply(Options.java:271)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Options.fn(Options.java:237)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.Options.fn(Options.java:226)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.helper.IfHelper.apply(IfHelper.java:51)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.Block.merge(Block.java:160)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:128)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.TemplateList.merge(TemplateList.java:61)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:128)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.BaseTemplate.apply(BaseTemplate.java:115)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.ForwardingTemplate.apply(ForwardingTemplate.java:82)
        at com.github.jknack.handlebars.internal.ForwardingTemplate.apply(ForwardingTemplate.java:60)
        at com.XXX.YYY.utils.HandlebarUtils.render(HandlebarUtils.java:80)
        at com.XXX.YYY.AthenaLayeredAsset.createLayeredHtml(AthenaLayeredAsset.java:68)
        at com.XXX.YYY.AthenaSlickCarousel.generateNarrowCarouselHTML(AthenaSlickCarousel.java:27)
        at com.XXX.YYY.TestAthenaLayeredAsset.testNarrowCarouselSimple(TestAthenaLayeredAsset.java:387)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
        at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java#templates-prefix-and-suffix) help?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up classpath paths and local absolute paths.

Comment: How is this Maven related?

Comment: Would either of you be willing to answer this formally?  It is going to "auto assign" the bounty tomorrow and obv I cant get it ;)

Comment: Tassos and Roman, Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Basically you need to be sure your templates are in your classpath and be sure the TemplateLoader knows where your "partials" are.**

After dropping this error long ago, I finally figured out how to be sure the directory that has ALL of my templates is included in the classpath.  I am sure there is more than one way to do this and maven experts might know a better one but I used:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html

Then in order to be sure your TemplateLoader knows where your "partials" are you can use setPrefix

https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java

or the version we are using there is an option in the constructor:

protected static final TemplateLoader loader =
            new ClassPathTemplateLoader("/partials/");

Much thanks to Roman and Tassos Bassoukos for the hints!!